# location is not updating in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an issue with `$location.path`. When i change my state it's not updating. Here is my `$stateProvider`

```
$stateProvider
  .state('state1', {
    url: 'url1',
    component: 'component1'
  })
  .state('state2', {
    url: 'url2',
    component: 'component2'
  });
```

When i change my route the ui will update. Here is my index.html code

```
   <header></header>
   <div class="container-fluid" id="page-content" ui-view></div>
   <footer></footer>
```

When i change any route view only update based on the state. I need to access the current state name in header & footer templates. Here is my header.js file contains,

```
 angular
.module('myApp') 
.component('header', {
  templateUrl: 'header.html',
  controller: headerController
});
function headerController($stateParams, $state, $location) {
   console.log($location.path());
   console.log($state.current.name);
}
```

In the above code when i change to another state it is not updating. Someone suggest a solution for this.

Comment: Did you try with hard refresh or by removing browser's cache ?

Comment: Ya i tried, Not working. Issue is header template is not refreshing. So the state is not updating. Is there any way to pass the $state into header.js?

Comment: Can you share any live demo with complete code?